# Oracle using REGEXP_REPLACE - leave letters, "-" and "\", except last letter

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have this string: `DOT-COM\NVIDIA_1d`

I want to extract it using **REGEXP_REPLACE** to this output:

```
DOT-COM\NVIDIA
```

So far I'm only here:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('DOT-COM\NVIDIA_1d', '[^-A-Z\]', '')  
  FROM dual;
```

Which outputs to:

```
DOT-COM\NVIDIAd
```

**Last letter, which I want to exclude, allways comes after **"_"** character.**

How could I change this expression to work my needs ?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply match on the pattern `_[^_]+$`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('DOT-COM\NVIDIA_1d', '_[^_]+$', '')  
FROM dual;
```

This regex pattern matches:

- `_` an underscore
- `[^_]+` followed by one or more non underscore characters
- `$` at the end of the string

Comment: thanks ! Could you elaborate this expression a bit ?

Comment: I have just added an explanation.